# Not able to load font node-canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas, draw, node-canvas

I am trying to use `Fira` font but for some reason I am not able to do it.

```
registerFont('./fira.ttf', { family: 'Fira', weight: 700 });
ctx.font = '50px "Fira"';
```

This gives:

```
(process:14880): Pango-WARNING **: 20:25:33.039: couldn't load font "Fira Code Light Not-Rotated 50px", falling back to "Sans Light Not-Rotated 50px", 
expect ugly output.

(process:14880): Pango-WARNING **: 20:25:33.043: couldn't load font "Fira Code Light 50px", falling back to "Sans Light 50px", expect ugly output.
```

and with:

```
registerFont('./fira.ttf', { family: 'Fira', weight: 700 });
ctx.font = '50px';
```

I think it gives the right font but it's too small

Answer (score 0):

The font rendering, which is done with Pango, does not find the font you registered.

You should try to change the family name, probably to `Fira Code`. Please check out this issue for some details: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1608